# Get raw with value 1% above average with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I Use Pandas with Python 3.xx. I would like to find the row where the value of the "High" is 1% higher than the average of the next 3 "High" values.

```
            Date    Open    High     Low   Close    Volume
 0 1608062400000  592.32  593.37  592.00  592.01  9670.229
 1 1608062700000  592.01  592.59  591.49  591.59  4165.193
 2 1608063000000  591.59  591.99  591.58  591.94  1383.861
 3 1608063300000  591.92  592.59  591.61  592.21  3658.069
 4 1608063600000  592.22  600.43  590.44  590.72  6557.817
 5 1608063900000  590.75  591.22  590.67  590.99  3750.567
 6 1608064200000  590.99  591.50  590.80  591.12  5969.057
 7 1608064500000  591.13  591.45  590.80  591.17  3219.910
 8 1608064800000  591.17  592.20  591.08  591.92  2744.831
 9 1608065100000  591.92  592.21  591.61  591.72  2313.002
```

Here raw 4 is the result excpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df=df.assign(av=df.High.rolling(3).mean())#Compute average of three consecutive rows
df[((df.High-df.av)/df.av*100).round(0).eq(2)]#Apply query and filter desired row
```

Comment: Can you explain the second line please, how does it works as a filter ? Let's say I want now 2% instead of 1%.

Comment: Edited my answer for you. Let me know if that helps. `eq` jus same as `=`

Comment: Brillant!
It helped a lot. Thank you.